# Docker Bridge Network TCP Restransmission

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We have setup three docket containers

1. PHP
2. nginx
3. FluentD

Docker is running on bridge network mode,  we have find huge TCP retransmission (18%) from Docker.

Docker Version is: **Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4**

Anyone facing similar issues or any work around  ?

[image]

Comment: Just solve the issue  by using host network mode.

Comment: Any reason for this? I am also seeing this packet re-transmission and its actually killing the reason docker is used anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Same workaround mentioned by "solvease"(Feb 5 at 8:58) > use '--network host' or 'network_mode: "host"' for docker-compose definition.

Comment: Maybe try to use different linux base image. Same issue o with image based on Alpine. With debian base image used problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

We have had a similar issue when instance network MTU was 1450 due to VXLAN usage but docker by default creates bridged network with MTU 1500.

Configuring /etc/docker/daemon.json to be like:

```
{
  "mtu": 1400
}
```

And restarting docker fixed it for us.
Usage of host network also works but it limits docket usage a lot.
For docker-compose use network and define MTU as well, e.g.

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    command: redis-server
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
    backend:
      driver: bridge
      driver_opts:
        com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1400
```

This behaviour describe here:
https://mlohr.com/docker-mtu/ and here
https://sylwit.medium.com/how-we-spent-a-full-day-figuring-out-a-mtu-issue-with-docker-4d81fdfe2caf